# HttpServlet side by side Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I'm trying to deploy, on App Engine, a server with google cloud endpoints with also a "regular" HttpServlet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
version="2.5"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.example.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AssetsServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.servlet.AssetServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AssetsServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/assets</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.api.LeadAPI</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

The google cloud endpoints class is in the `LeadAPI` and the HttpServlet is the `AssetServlet`. When I try to make requests to `/assets`, the server says it cannot find the endpoint.

Do you know if it is possible to do what I'm trying to achieve? From the documentation I cannot figure it out.